# What are all the available parameters for query_posts?

Tags: themes, query-posts

The WordPress codex page for [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) states that it does not cover all the parameters which query_posts takes:

> ### Parameters
>
> This is not an exhaustive list yet. It is meant to show some of the more common things possible with setting your own queries

I couldn't find a reference of all the parameters which are accepted by query_posts, though, even in just a simple list form. Is there a cheat-sheet or something similar available with this data?

Comment: **You should never use `query_posts`, it is bad practice, use `WP_Query` or the `pre_get_posts` filter instead**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Below is everything from WordPress 3.0.1 found in the `parse_query()` function of **/wp-includes/query.php** `(lines 1246-1550)`.
However, it's possible for a plugin to add parameters and so a list can never be fully complete:

- `attachment`
- `attachment_id`
- `author`
- `author_name`
- `cat`
- `category__and`
- `category__in`
- `category__not_in`
- `category_name`
- `comments_popup`
- `day`
- `error`
- `feed`
- `hour`
- `m`
- `minute`
- `monthnum`
- `name`
- `order`
- `orderby`
- `p`
- `page_id`
- `page`
- `paged`
- `pagename`
- `post__in`
- `post__not_in`
- `post_status`
- `post_type`
- `preview`
- `robots`
- `s`
- `sentence`
- `second`
- `static`
- `subpost`
- `subpost_id`
- `tag__and`
- `tag__in`
- `tag__not_in`
- `tag_id`
- `tag_slug__and`
- `tag_slug__in`
- `tag`
- `taxonomy` - (pre 3.1)
- `tb`
- `term` - (pre 3.1)
- `w`
- `withcomments`
- `withoutcomments`
- `year`

  **Pre WP 3.1**
- `meta_key`
- `meta_value`

  **Since WP 3.1**
- `fields`
- `meta_query`
- `tax_query`

Comment: I was JUST looking for this list yesterday!

Comment: If you could re-edit your question and make it community wiki, we could all keep it up-to-date when things change. Parameter types (formats: int or string?, multiple values?) would also be nice.

Comment: @Mike - I've added some missing query vars into your answer and also added some new 3.1 query vars in.

Comment: @Mike - No problem, i'm sure there's a couple more missing, but seeing as we've covered the important ones i wasn't going to nit pick over having every last one(there's a good few in there that noone will ever use already - sentence or second are two i've **never** seen used)... :)

Comment: @t31os - FYI I'm currently working on a plugin that will make sure of all of these, and more which I am **_very_** excited about. It's a next generation URL routing plugin.  Interested?

Comment: @Mike - Sounds interesting, i assume this ties in with [trac ticket 12935](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12935) and associated discussion. Curious to say the least.. :)

Comment: @t31os - RE:#12935; yes, exactly.  Do you have use-case issues with URLs?  I'll be looking for some people who really need advanced URL control to beta test it and make recommendations.

Comment: Unfortunately not(i only use WP locally apart from my blog), it will be of little use to me, i'd still be curious nonetheless though... :-D

Comment: @t31os - Email me?  See [my profile page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/89/mikeschinkel) for contact info.

Comment: @Mike - Will do tomorrow matey, heading off to bed shortly... :)

Answer (score 7):

If you can read PHP code, you can take a look at the function `parse_query($query)` in class `WP_Query` of file `wp-includes\query.php`

The supported arguments are all listed and managed there.

Comment: +1, the code is the authoritative reference. (Not the codex, or the function comment/docblock.)

Answer (score 2):

I use the Codex page for WP_Query.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

The list may not be exhaustive but it is useful, fairly comprehensive and up-to-date. I believe that WP_Query and query_posts share the same parameters.