# Else statement not triggering after a failed if statement

Tags: conditional-tags, wordpress-version

I am working on a client site and the statement I wrote 6 months ago seems to have stopped working after the WordPress update to 3.8 I can't see or figure out why.

There are no errors appearing it just returns empty divs with post Id's in the class field.
If the the if statement is false then it needs to echo out different data. But sadly it isn't it still spits out the the first H3 tag.

```
<div class="span4">
    <?php // Blog post query
    $today = date('Y-m-d');

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $currentID = get_the_ID();
    query_posts(array(
       'post' => 'ID', 
       'post_type' => 'foodswaps', 
       'posts_per_page' => 3, 
       'meta_key' => '00.event-date',
       'meta_value' => $today,
       'meta_compare' => '>=',
       'orderby' => 'meta_value',
       'order' => 'ASC' 
     ));

    if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <h3 class="calendar">Upcoming Swaps</h3>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div <?php post_class('clear-spacer no-margin'); ?>>                                    
                <?php 
                $field_name = "00.event-date";
                $listEventDate = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field_name, true);
                if (($listEventDate == 'E.g. yyyy-mm-dd') && ($listEventDate == '')) { ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php  the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ); ?>">
                    <h4><?php the_title();?></h4>
                    <?php 
                    $converted = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($listEventDate));
                    $reversedDate = date('jS F Y', strtotime($converted));

                    echo $reversedDate;?>
                </a>
                <?php  } ?>
        </div><!-- /.post_class -->
    <?php // end of blog post loop.
    endwhile; wp_reset_query(); // end of the loop and reset the query. 
    else: 
        echo '<h3 class="theblog">Our Social Networks</h3>';
        echo '<p>Why not visit us on our social networks?</p>';
    endif;?>
```

Comment: Try properly formatting your query (i.e. dumping the improper use of `query_posts()`), and then see if the issue persists.

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and/or »[Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)«, more information about the WordPress Development model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a problem with your *if-else-statement*, so I'm thinking the problem origins somewhere else. You say you get no errors, I guess you have [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) enabled. Besides, did you debug and inspect - `var_dump` or `print_r` it - the *`$wp_query` object*, to see if it is really empty, has no posts.

Another thing, you are using `query_posts()`, which you shouldn't. I don't want to replicate the argument for that, so see those two questions for more information:

- [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/22534)
- [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/22534)

This should clear now, better use `pre_get_posts` or `WP_Query` or `get_posts`.

One more remark, you are using:

- `'post' => 'ID'`

in your arguments array, but post *isn't* a valid parameter - see this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/46/22534) for more information.

Comment: Yes there is definitely data there. if the I change != to == it spits out the data I expect to see. 

I will rebuild the query to see if that helps.

Comment: Ok, not sure if I totally grab your sentence, but I would say, definitely rebuild your query and if the problem remains come back with the new information. @DLaverick